# How to achieve Pagination in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement to implement a paging within a List View page. Here I am  displaying hundreds or thousands of records in a table hence the need for paging functionality.

An infinite scrolling down approach is not viable due to the number of records. Same as attached image. [image]

Comment: Did you try carousel view? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/introduction

Comment: google `xamarin forms listview pagination`.  (I wouldn't personally use CarouselView to do this.)

Comment: According to your statement, you have a lot of data, whether you use a database, you can control the displayed data according to the number of pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView>
<SomeDataContentView Data={Binding SelectedData} />
</ScrollView>


<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemSource={Binding ListOfPageNumber}
x:Name="SomeStack"
Orientation="Horizontal">
   <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Button Text={Binding .}
Command={Binding Path=BindingContext.SelectPage_Command, Source={x:Reference SomeStack}
CommandParameter={Binding .}
</DataTemplate>
</BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
```

ViewModel:

```
public SelectPage_Command = new Command((param) =>
{
   var pageNo = (int)param;

SelectedData = DataDividedByPage[pageNo];
});
```

SomeDataContentView.cs:

```
SomeDataContentView : ContentView

        public static readonly BindableProperty DataProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
nameof(Data), typeof(string), typeof(SomeDataContentView ), defaultValue: "", propertyChanged: DoSomethingWhenDataChanged);
        public string Data
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(DataProperty perty);
            set => SetValue(DataProperty , value);
        }
```

And create your SomeDataContentView.xaml to show the data how you want it.

This is probably how I'd do it.

I've done it from memory and skipped one or two things. But I'll come back to it later, if you need me to.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //How to add Pagination in Xamarin Forms without using ViewModel 

  //Step 1-> First , we will add ListView property -> ItemAppearing
  //In EmployeeTestListing.xaml page , we need to write 
  <ListView x:Name="lstEmployee"
                  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                  ItemTapped="lstEmployee_ItemTapped"
                  Refreshing="lstEmployee_Refreshing"
                  ItemAppearing="lstEmployee_ItemAppearing"  
                  HasUnevenRows="True">


//Step 2->  In EmployeeTestListing.xaml.cs page , we need to write      

 public partial class EmployeeTestListing : ContentPage
{
      ObservableCollection<EmployeeTestListingModel> employeeList;
      
           public EmployeeTestListing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        employeeList = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeTestListingModel>(); // Pagination
        lstEmployee.ItemsSource = employeeList; // Pagination
    }   
    
    
    
    public void LoadData()
    {
    
                  var response = await httpService.Post("EmployeeTest/getemployeetests", employeeTest, false);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseUserDataString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                RootEmployeeTestListingModel employeeTestClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootEmployeeTestListingModel>(responseUserDataString);

                if (employeeTestClass.data.Count == 0)
                {
                    loader.IsVisible = false;
                    loader.IsRunning = false;
                    lstEmployee.IsVisible = false;
                    lblNoData.IsVisible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //For Pagination include below foreach code
                    foreach (var item in employeeTestClass.data)
                    {
                        employeeList.Add(item);
                    }
                    
                    lstEmployee.IsVisible = true;
                    loader.IsVisible = false;
                    loader.IsRunning = false;
                    lblNoData.IsVisible = false;
                }
            }
    }
    
       //Pagination Scrolling Method ItemAppearing
    private async void lstEmployee_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        if (employeeList.Count == 0) return;
        try
        {
            var item = (EmployeeTestListingModel)e.Item;
            if (employeeList.Count >= pageSize)
            {
                if (item == employeeList.Last())
                {
                    pageSize += pageSize;
                    lstEmployee.IsVisible = true;
                    await LoadData();
                }
            }
        }
        catch 
        {

        }
    }
    
    
    

}
```